# How to confirm successfull communication between my server and GCM server

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am following Google official tutorial for demo Google Cloud Messaging from http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/demo.html . I set up the gcm-demo-client and gcm-demo-server.

Now, when I run applicaiton, its works well. The device is registered to my server. Then when I click sent message in my server to invoke, its says the message is sent. I assume the process sent message correctly to GCM since its their official sample server for tutorial.
However, my message is not delivered to client applications.

When I see report status about my project in GOOGLE API CONSOLE, the request per day info are 0. Should not it be changed if my server sent message to GCM to deliver to registered device?

Is there anyway to confirm that my server message has been successfully delivered to GCM first? If i confirm this, then can confirm that message is being late.

I tried with both server and browser API key. DO it take time to deliver?

Thanks in advance for your support and any help.

Answer (score 0):

The demo in the tutorial works well. Finally, I was able to get the push message. However, the message was delivered late then expected in about 15 min. Why is it happening so? I don't think its reliable to use.